# Python 3.3.3: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pygame

I have a python 2.7.6 program I want to convert to 3.3.3.

I am getting an error:

```
File "H:\My Game Python 3,3\MoonSurvival.py", line 199, in run
  self.moon.levelStructure[x][y] = None
```

The Traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\My Game Python 3,3\MoonSurvival.py", line 591, in <module>
    Game().run()
  File "H:\My Game Python 3,3\MoonSurvival.py", line 199, in run
    self.moon.levelStructure[x][y] = None
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

But when I look at the code for the `levelStructure` there is nothing wrong. This is the code that assigns levelStructure:

```
tempBlock = Block(x*64, y*64)
# add block to both and self.levelStructure
self.levelStructure[x][y] = tempBlock
```

As you can see the `levelStructure` is tempBlock.  As it is multiplying, it seems to be giving a float.  I know with division it is two slashes `/`.  I have tried to multiply '*' but I still get the error.  I am not entirely familiar with 3.3.3 syntax as I generally use 2.7.6.

Block code:

```
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('data/images/moon.jpg')

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def render(self, surface):
        surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

What causes this error?

Comment: What is `Block` and can we see the code for it?

Comment: If `x` and `y` are floats before the multiplication, they will remain floats after. Multiplying by an integer won't change that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're converting from Python 2.7 -> Python 3.x, it's almost CERTAINLY an issue with floor division.

I'm not sure where exactly you're generating your `x` and `y`, but if at any point you divide those numbers by anything, make sure you use the `//` operator in Python 3 if you expect an integer result.

In Python 2, `5/2 == 2` and you had to do `5/2.0` to get the floating point result. In Python 3, `5/2 == 2.5` and you have to do `5//2` to get the floored integer result of the division. Chances are whenever you're operating on your `x` and `y`, you're dividing it by something that in Python 2 gave you an integer but in Python 3 is leaving you with that floating point, so when you try to use it as a list index...BOOM

Comment: I have been using the // to get an integer because I had to do that to fix my collision. And that was the only place the // was needed as no other divisions are used.

Comment: Not sure why your `x` and `y` aren't integers then. Before your line `self.levelStructure[x][y] = tempBlock` why don't you do `print("x is {} and its type is {}".format(x,type(x)))` and repeat for `y`, then tell me the result.

Comment: Ok will try that now. Just tried that and nothing was printed at all :/

Comment: @GhostFrag1 if nothing was printed and you put those lines BEFORE your call to `self.levelStructure[x][y]`, then that is NOT the line you're throwing an exception on. Indeed in the stack trace it looks like line 199, `self.moon.levelStructure[x][y]`. Try putting the same print statements before that.

Comment: Ok. Will try now. Done that now and I am getting this:`x is 4.0 and its type is <class 'float'>
y is 4.0 and its type is <class 'float'>`

Comment: @GhostFrag1 Okee doke, so that tells you that somewhere somehow it's being assigned as a float. Follow your execution flow from the point you assign `x` and `y` until your print line. I guarantee that SOMEWHERE in there, you're doing something that makes it a float :)

Comment: Indeed there will be. Going to do some hard looking. Going to check for any / in the mix. I feel so stupid now.. I had a look and literally right ABOVE the print there were some /'s...

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a float as the index of an Array that only accepts whole numbers like integers.

**How to reproduce this error as simply as possible in Python 3.3.3:**

```
>>> stuffi = []
>>> stuffi.append("foobar")
>>> print(stuffi[0])
foobar
>>> stuffi[0] = "failwhale"
>>> print(stuffi[0])
failwhale
>>> stuffi[0.99857] = "skipper"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

Try adding integer typcasts to the variables, so that:

```
self.levelStructure[x][y] = tempBlock
```

becomes:

```
self.levelStructure[int(x])[int(y)] = tempBlock
```

If that works, you may be able to just add that to:

```
tempBlock = Block(x*64, y*64)
```

so that it looks like:

```
tempBlock = Block(int(x*64), int(y*64))
```

Comment: Will definitely give this a try looks like this could help as it is definitely being told to be an int. Tried and didn't seem to make a difference. The game would not run and many more errors occurred.

Comment: This may end up working, but is probably not the "Right" answer.

Comment: Casting a floats to an int before using it as an index to an array is a "duct tape programmer style sweep the problem under the rug" kind of solution.  It's better to address the bug at it's source and make sure floats can't come out of the calculation that generates the array index.  If there are marbles all over the dance hall floor, the solution is to remove the marbles, not get everyone big boots.