# What is wrong with my Python binary search code?

Tags: python, binary-search

I'm still unsure as to why this code doesn't work as I have attempted to right every wrong that the error returns to me, however I am still clueless.

```
import random
import math

numbas=[]

def randomnumbers():
    return random.randint(1, 9)

for i in range(10):
    numbas.append(randomnumbers())

def binarysearch(x):
    newlist=x
    newlist.sort()
    ettiqete=len(newlist)/2
    search=int(input("Search for a number: "))
    while(True):
        if type(newlist[ettiqete]) is float:
            betternet = newlist[ettiqete]
            if search == math.floor(newlist[ettiqete]):
                print("Wayyy.")
                break
            elif search > math.floor(newlist[ettiqete]):
                newlist=newlist[ettiqete-1:0]
            else:
                newlist=newlist[ettiqete+1:len(newlist)]
```

The error is this, I have also posted the two steps I took.

```
binarysearch()
Search for a number: 7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    binarysearch()
  File "C:/Users/djames1/Documents/Pithon/binarysearch.py", line 18, in binarysearch
    if type(newlist[ettiqete]) is float:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float
```

Comment: ettiqete is a float` - which index do you intend on looking up when the list has a length of 3 so you end up looing up `newlist[0.5]`?

Comment: my guess is, in python 3, with an odd-length list, `ettiqete=len(newlist)/2` will give you a float

Comment: Here the // operator might be useful, rounding down the result in Python 3.

Comment: See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609227/python-3-3-3-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-not-float